# Angular form 1.3 tightly coupled

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

Does anyone of you think that the form in angular 1.3 is causing tightly coupling between the controller and the DOM? This is an anti pattern of Angular.

For example, when giving a form the name='formExample' attribute, to set it to dirty or invalid programmily, in the controller we have to do $scope.formExample.$setDirty()

This is a bad practice!

Waiting to hear your thoughts!

Example :

```
this.onSaveClicked = function () {
        that.saveMessage = that.SAVING_IN_PROGRESS;

        //Update project with changes
        ProjectsBLL.update($scope.entities.project.Model, function (data) {
            $scope.entities.project.Model = data;
            $scope.configurationForm.$setPristine();
            that.saveMessage = that.SAVING_FINISHED;
        }, null)
    }
```

Comment: What alternate way you suggest??

Comment: Can you give a specific example in code of exactly when you use `$setDirty` in the controller? Then answers can give alternative ways of coding it up.

Comment: I have an example regarding setPristine(). Only when user pressed 'cancel' and some condition exists then call setPristine().

Comment: @einav Can you put that as code in the question, and perhaps a link to a Plunker?

Comment: @einav I meant if you can edit the question and put the code in it, so it can be answered without having to read the comments, and code reasonably formatted.

Comment: tight coupling between the view and the DOM? The view is the DOM. What's your question exactly? What would you like to be different?

Comment: I fixed my question. Its tightly between the view and the controller

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want the following line in the controller

```
$scope.configurationForm.$setPristine();
```

To achieve this, one way is to:

- Change `ProjectsBLL.update` to return a promise rather than accept a callback (how to do this is probably beyond the scope of this question). Then also return the derived promise from `then` from the function in the controller:

  ```
  this.onSaveClicked = function () {
    that.saveMessage = that.SAVING_IN_PROGRESS;

    //Update project with changes
    return ProjectsBLL.update($scope.entities.project.Model).then(function (data) {
      $scope.entities.project.Model = data;
      that.saveMessage = that.SAVING_FINISHED;
    });
  }
  ```
- And then use a custom directive rather than `ng-click` to call the save function. There are probably a few ways of doing this, but one is to add one that takes a function as an attribute:

  ```
  <button type="button" my-submit="onSaveClicked()">Save</button>
  ```

  which adds a manual `click` listener, calls the passed function on click, and after its returned promise is resolved, calls `$setPristine()` on a `require`ed form:

  ```
  app.directive('mySubmit', function($parse) {
    return {
      require: '^form',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, formController) {
        var callback = $parse(attrs.mySubmit);
        element.on('click', function() {
          callback(scope, {}).then(function() {
            formController.$setPristine();
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
  ```

A version of this, just using a `$timeout` to simulate a call to `$http` can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/IdcfQ4N9MhDKdvyorzeO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I didn't understand the first way. How can I achieve the $setPristine()?

Comment: @einav I've only given one way. I've just split it into 2 bullet points.